# Solving Schrodinger equation in rectangular coordinates for triatomic reactions

Tags: schroedinger-equation, molecular-dynamics

I want to simulate triatomic reactions without going to spherical/hyperspherical system. I need some resources such as books or papers where the theory of triatomic reactions is given in rectangular coordinates exclusively. So far I haven't found anything exclusively for triatomic reactions in rectangular coordinates. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: With just the three nuclei you already have nine spatial coordinates. How many electrons are your atoms going to have, and how are you going to deal with all those coordinates?

Comment: Triatomic reactions are very rare.